# how to run an online java source tree via netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, kerberos

I'm trying to run java source code of Kerberos in Netbeans.
I'm using centos 7 and netbeans 8.
You can see the source code [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=ikvm-openjdk-master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/Realm.java).
So far, I created the Project and packages, and also classes (means all the staff under the krb5 folder). When i run the project, it says SUCCESSFUL, but nothing happens.
what should I do?
please hellllllp

Comment: How are you running it? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I'm expecting it to give a ticket to a client..